# use php to change a html elements inner text

Tags: php, javascript

I have a basic form, which i need to put some validation into, I have a span area and I want on pressing of the submit button, for a predefined message to show in that box if a field is empty.

Something like

```
if ($mytextfield = null) {
    //My custom error text to appear in the spcificed #logggingerror field
}
```

I know i can do this with jquery (document.getElementbyId('#errorlogging').innerHTML = "Text Here"), but how can I do this with PHP?

Bit of a new thing for me with php, any help greatly appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: Are you wanting to run PHP on the client, or submit to the server and return a result to the client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it it a couple of ways. You can create a $error variable. Make it so that the $error is always created (even if everything checks out OK) but it needs to be empty if there is no error, or else the value must be the error.

Do it like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(empty($_POST['somevar'])){
        $error = "Somevar was empty!";
    }
}
?>
<h2>FORM</h2>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="somevar" />

<?php
if(isset($error) && !empty($error)){
    ?>
    <span class="error"><?= $error; ?></span>
    <?php
}
?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want change it dynamically in client-side, there is no way but ajax. PHP works at server-side and you have to use post/get requests.

Answer (score 3):

Form fields sent to php in a $_REQUEST, $_GET or $_POST variables...

For validate the field param you may write like this:

```
if(strlen($_REQUEST['username']) < 6){
 echo 'false';
}
else{
 echo 'true';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do anything client-side with PHP. You need Javascript for that. If you really need PHP (for instance to do a check to the database or something), you can use Javascript to do an Ajax call, and put the return value inside a div on the page.

Comment: Sure you can, it just takes a roundtrip (postback?) to the server and back. `:)`

Comment: @JaredFarrish so that's no longer 'client-side'.. ;)

Comment: Point out where the OP says it must be client-side. It's possible the OP *implies* this, but it's pretty straight-forward to affect what a client sees using a server, it's just not on client-side validation.

Comment: No, I said you can't. You need Javascript to change the innerHTML of a div.

Comment: I think you're reading into the question something it doesn't say (but, who knows, the OP may mean that). To wit, the OP says jQuery will accomplish it but then references a DOM method, so intent is possibly muddied.

Comment: Also, technically (and this is just a hint), a trip AJAX or otherwise to the server is not needed to check if a value is empty. `:)` (*To be honest, it's a poorly phrased question that's difficult, at least for me, to understand what the OP is asking.*)